# neo4j import tool START_ID/END_ID is possible to pass another field and not the id of the Node

Tags: neo4j

I'm working with neo4j version 3.1.3
neo4j import tool START_ID/END_ID is possible to pass another field and not the id of the Node ? make a match between another property the START_ID and END_ID 
I know that in cypher it's possible but i need to start the graph with import tool because there are large files and take too much time to insert the data to neo4j through cypher.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **:START_ID** and **:END_ID** in the relationship csv files have to be an **:ID** in the node csv files. These have to be unique, there's no other way that a correct match (read: a correct relationship) can be made.

You can read the exact specification (and reason why things are the way they are) in the first paragraph of https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom